# Use chrome app in terminal

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I would know if it's possible to make a chrome app who could be launched in the terminal without chrome UI. Example:

```js
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    console.log("Hello world!);
});
```

```
imac:bin$ chrome --app-id=<my-app-id>
Hello world!
imac:bin$
```

I think not, but could you confirm. Thanks

Comment: When you say without chrome UI, do you mean you want your app to start without an application window, or just without the Chrome browser opening up?

Comment: What did you get when you tried your example?

Comment: @mmocny Either one or other. MarcRochkind, when I try, I have a subliminal window then nothing.

Comment: Why do you want to use a Chrome App as a shell tool? It *is* possible to some extent, but not without a wrapper of some kind. Unless you need a complete rendering engine, you'd better use a shell script (or if you want to use JavaScript, Node.js).

Comment: For some experiences, use chrome's api for a server where, for example, indexeddb would be a server side database.

Comment: You can use [nw.js](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/) (based off Node.js and Chromium) and you can do e.g. `process.stdout.write("IDBObjectStore: " + window.IDBObjectStore)` or you could just use Node.js and [this indexeddb module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/indexeddb-js) (or some of [many other database modules](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/database))

Answer (score 2):

I use this line to start chrome apps from the command line, on OSX:

```
open -n -a Google\ Chrome\ Canary --args --user-data-dir=/tmp/temp_chrome_data_dir --load-and-launch-app=...
```

The key flags are `--user-data-dir` to create an isolated profile, and `--load-and-launch-app` to start a chrome app automatically.  I use the `open` command to resolve the path to chrome application on OSX, but you can just an explicit path instead:

```
/path/to/Google\ Chrome\ Canary --user-data-dir=/tmp/temp_chrome_data_dir --load-and-launch-app=...
```

That said, this will pop open a chrome browser window as well.  I'm not yet sure how to get around that, but I will investigate.  (My workaround for local development is to just minimize the window once, and it won't pop up any more).

Comment: I think OP is more interested in outputting things in STDOUT. Which I doubt is possible.

Comment: When I try I get a pop with `Could not load extension from ''. Manifest file missing or unreadable`

Comment: The above only works with apps not extensions, though by the error perhaps your path is just not pointing to the folder which holds the root of the app (should have a manifest.json, should load from chrome:extensions "load unpacked extension" button)

Comment: @Druxtan Try loading it manually at `chrome://extensions`. Then you can often see actual errors in loading the app, whereas loading it with `--load-and-launch-app` always gives the same vague and often misleading message.